# Which is better way to check what option a user select in Ussd Program using PHP (8)

Tags: php

I'm building a simple USSD based payment gateway in PHP (version 8) using African'stalking testing environment

I don't know which is the better way to check what level or option that a current user selects or interacts with

My current codes..

```
     public function handleSession(Request $request)
    {
       $text=$request->input('text');
       // We split the response(text) to an array
      // It helps us to check which option the current user selects
  
       $level = explode("*", $text);
        // Initially, the response is an empty string
       if ( $text == "" ) {
         // We send our ussd menu
           $response = $this->welcomeInterface();
       }
       // If user selects the first option from the menu (first level menu)
       
       if(isset($level[0]) && $level[0] == 1 && !isset($level[1]))
       {
           $response = $this->buyerOptionsInterface();
       }
        // If user select the second option from the menu
       if(isset($level[0]) && $level[0] == 2 && !isset($level[1]))
       {
           $response = $this->sellerOptionsInterface();
       }
      // If user select the third option from the menu (last option)
       if(isset($level[0]) && $level[0] == 3  && !isset($level[1]))
       {
           $response= $this->termsAndConditionsInterface();
          
       }

       // If user selects the first option from our first level menu, and first option of second level menu 
       if(isset($level[0]) && $level[0] == 1 && isset($level[1]) && $level[1] == 1 && !isset($level[2])) {
           $response = $this->insertSellerPhoneNumber();
       }

      // If user select the first option of first level menu,and first option of second level menu and first option of third level menu
       if(isset($level[0]) && $level[0] == 1 && isset($level[1]) && $level[1] == 1 && isset($level[2]) && $level[2] == 1 && !isset($level[3])) {
         $response = $this->insertPrice();
       }

           header('Content-type: text/plain');
           echo $response;
   }
```

The codes work,but they become more difficult to read when user is let say fifth levels down

Which is better way to refactor above code,the framework is Laravel (Version 8)

Comment: If your code works and you want a review, then try [codereview.se].  I don't think I understand all of the logical requirements.  Maybe some sample data and expected outcomes would give context/clarity.  Do you want to map levels to callbacks?

Comment: I want to shorten the condition in if else statements,read my codes above